Gitlab Protected Variables only in protected branches. need to skip the TF Plan within merge_request pipeline
I'm utilizing gitlab's opentofu CICD component to good effect.. BUT noticing it'd be nice to keep my cloud credentials protected .. but smooth out the merge_request pipeline (which is not protected and fails on TF PLAN command)
Is there some good way to either protect the merge_request pipeline OR skip the tf plan stage?
variables:
  TF_VAR_REGION: "sweden central"
  TF_VAR_PROJECT_NAME: "myproject"
  TF_VAR_ENVIRONMENT: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
  TF_STATE_NAME: ""

before_script:
  - |
    if [ "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" == "main" ]; then
      export TF_VAR_ENVIRONMENT="prd"
      export TF_STATE_NAME="prd"
    elif [ "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" == "staging" ]; then
      export TF_VAR_ENVIRONMENT="tst"
      export TF_STATE_NAME="tst"
    else
      export TF_VAR_ENVIRONMENT="dev-${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME,,}"
      export TF_STATE_NAME="dev-${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME,,}"
    fi

include:
  - template: Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml
  - component: $CI_SERVER_FQDN/components/opentofu/full-pipeline@0.25.0
    inputs:
      version: 0.25.0
      root_dir: terraform

stages: [validate, test, build, deploy, cleanup]


As you can seee TF Plan fails on merge requets

OpenTofu has been successfully initialized!
Planning failed. OpenTofu encountered an error while generating this plan.
╷
│ Error: No valid credential sources found
│ 
│   with provider["registry.opentofu.org/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on provider.tf line 2, in provider "aws":
│    2: provider "aws" {
│ 
│ Please see https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws
│ for more information about providing credentials.
│ 
│ Error: failed to refresh cached credentials, no EC2 IMDS role found,
│ operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, request canceled, context deadline
│ exceeded
│ 
╵


The terraform MR should be checked and tested before being merged in main branch, because main branch means real infra.
What would be the risk if the credentials are available to all MRs (branches)? The risk is changing the .gitlab-ci.yml by some user and retrieve the credentials or applying something that is not in main branch. The solution would be protecting the gitlab-ci.yml.
There are 3 solutions for this:

Push rules (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/push_rules.html)

Push rules are pre-receive Git hooks. gitlab-ci.yml can be added to it, and any push containing this file will be rejected.

Reference to another project
Protect .gitlab-ci.yml from change


A .gitlab-ci.yml may contain rules to deploy an application to the
production server. This deployment usually runs automatically after
pushing a merge request. To prevent developers from changing the
.gitlab-ci.yml, you can define it in a different repository. The
configuration can reference a file in another project with a
completely different set of permissions (similar to separating a
project for deployments). In this scenario, the .gitlab-ci.yml is
publicly accessible, but can only be edited by users with appropriate
permissions in the other project.

and referencing it in your project:
include:
  - project: 'gitlab-ci/models'
    ref: 'v1.2.0' #optional
    file:
      - 'terraform.yml'


pre-receive hooks (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html). Same as first solution, but using git directly.

